# Can the Angular CLI be used to build and deploy on a remote server via ssh?

Tags: deployment, build-pipeline

I'd like to use the Angular CLI to build the app and deploy it on my remote server via SSH. Is this feature available?

Comment: See the discussion on Stack overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52550228/can-the-angular-cli-be-used-to-build-and-deploy-on-a-remote-server-via-ssh

Answer (score 1):

You need to use continuous deployment tools.
Not available yet.